# Format date shown on DatePicker

Tags: date, datepicker, windows-phone-8.1, format

I created a Pivot Project on Visual Studio 2013.

I created the following control:

```
<DatePicker Header="Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,0,0" Width="341"/>
```

When I tap on it on my phone, it displays the date as M/D/Y. Is it possible to display it as D/M/Y?

Also, don't know if I should create another question, but how can I translate to pt-BR the day/month names shown within the control? As well as that "Choose a date".

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *DatePicker* format is using user's preferred language and region. This control will automatically look different, for my region it's day/month/year like you wish it to be. I've tried to force the control to use other language, but it seems to be taking it directly from phone settings. Some information you may find here at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965451.aspx):

> If you need to allow users to choose a date or select a time, use the standard date and time picker controls. These will automatically use the date and time formats for the user's preferred language and region.

The other bad news you can find [here at MSDN about formating that particular control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn308514.aspx):

> Note  This section applies to Windows Store apps using C++, C#, or Visual Basic. Formatting is ignored in Windows Phone Store apps.

So in current API it may be hard to change the formatting.

The good news is for the `CHOOSE DATE` text at the top - it's automatically localized, depending on user's language and region. So you don't have to worry about it if your app supports user's language. But I've not found way to change it to other text.

As for the text displayed inside the button before it's clicked, you can always use *Button* with *DatePickerFlyout*, a simple example with apropriate converter:

```xml
<Button Content="{Binding ElementName=chosenDate, Path=Date, Converter={StaticResource DateFormatConverter}}">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <DatePickerFlyout x:Name="chosenDate" />
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

and the converter class:

```cs
public class DateFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        DateTimeOffset chosen = (DateTimeOffset)value;
        return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", chosen.Day, chosen.Month, chosen.Year);
        // or use chosen.ToString() with format provider
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

Comment: I was running with on my phone using portuguese(language) and USA (region). Uninstalled the app, cleaned the solution, changed region to Brazil, rebooted phone and reinstalled the app. Didin't change a thing.

Comment: @GustavoMP Please check what language is the first one in Settings->Languages. Also check if your app supports `pt-BR` - do you have resources for them? Is it set as additional language?

Comment: That's it. Changed the language in the manifest to pt-br and created the resource. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GustavoMP Language in the manifest can be anything, the most important is that you have defined resources for target language, also if you use Multilingual App Toolkit, check apropriate checkbox in *additional languages*. Then when user has chosen target language in phone settings, the app will be installed/use apropriate strings.